# Nearest neighbour analysis from existing Excel sheet

Tags: qgis-3, proximity

[image]I learnt the Nearest Neighbor Analysis from [QGIS Tutorials and Tips](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html). The result of this analysis, see image below

[image: result]

I know that after running the distance to nearest hub analysis, it produces hub lines and when you open the attribute table of the hub lines, it shows where each point is mapped to. In my case, I already have an Excel sheet showing where each of the points is going to and I want to display them visually as it is already in the Excel sheet. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You probably need to import the excel sheet as a delimited text layer, then do some further processing to draw the lines. The exact details depend on what your excel data looks like. Please [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: What is the further processing to draw the line that should be done?

Comment: This is what I want to do with the 50,000 data set. Using create hub line under MMQGIS will generate new hub lines. Is there a way I can display the dataset the way it has been mapped on the excel sheet?

Comment: Can you add in the question how the excel looks like? Some rows of example